# How to install an application using passive cmd or force the installation

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

I have installed ODBC, now i'm trying to install a tool but every time I click on *run as administrator* it keeps saying "can't install". 
I did install it before using cmd but that was a long time ago.
This what I type:

```
AccessDatabaseEngine_x64_SP2.exe/passive
```

This is what I get:

> C:\Users\a8a>AccessDatabaseEngine_x64_SP2/passive
>   'AccessDatabaseEngine_x64_SP2' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just change the path from 
C:\Users\a8a>AccessDatabaseEngine_x64_SP2/passive
  to 
D:\Users\a8a>AccessDatabaseEngine_x64_SP2/passive  by creating a new Network mapping Drive